# android interaction between activity and countdowntimer

Tags: android, android-activity, countdowntimer

I have several activities that need to use a CountDownTimer:

```
cdt = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            if (millisUntilFinished / 1000 == 5){
                ct = MediaPlayer.create(Fractions.this, R.raw.clock_tik);
                ct.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer ct) {
                        ct.reset();
                        ct.release();   
                    }
                });
                if (isVisible)
                    ct.start();
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("0");

            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Fractions.this, R.raw.end);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();   
                }
            });
            if (isVisible)
                mp.start();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Questions.this, Results.class);
            intent.putExtra("numberOfCorrectAnswers", numberOfCorrectAnswers);
            intent.putExtra("numberOfQuestions", numberOfQuestions);
            intent.putExtra("nameOfTable", "questions");
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transitions_fade1, R.anim.transitions_fade2);
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
```

It works nicely when it's in the onCreate of each activity, but
I want to put it in a separate class:

```
public class myCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
```

I'm facing several problems:
1. how will myCountDownTimer know the values of the variables that I want to pass when changing activity (those in the putExtra)? these variables change as time progresses, so I can't pass them in the constructor.
2. I can't call overridePendingTransition from myCountDownTimer class. Says it is undefined for the type myCountDownTimer.
3. The isVisible variable that I use there get set by the onPause method in the activities. How will myCountDownTimer know it's value?

Comment: Do you need a common CountDownTimer ?

Comment: No, but they all do the same, so I prefer not having duplicated code.

Comment: I mean CountDownTimer will always continue for each activity right? Or it will reset always?

Comment: For avoiding code duplication you can create a Base class for all these activities.